# Java: How to sort array upon return

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

How can I sort the arrays in my IF statements either alphabetically or numerically (pg nums)? Mind you, `Arrays.sort()` will not compile when used. I'm trying to sort the RETURNED values, not the initial inputs.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LibraryBookSort
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String title, author;

        int x;
        int pages, sortBy;

        LibraryBook[] titleArray = new LibraryBook[5];
        LibraryBook[] authorArray = new LibraryBook[5];
        LibraryBook[] pagesArray = new LibraryBook[5];

        for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            titleArray[x] = new LibraryBook();
            authorArray[x] = new LibraryBook();
            pagesArray[x] = new LibraryBook();
        }
        //User Input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            //TitleInput
            System.out.print("Enter the title of a book: ");
            title = input.nextLine();
            titleArray[x].setBook(title);

            //Author Input
            System.out.print("Enter the author of this book: ");
            author = input.nextLine();
            authorArray[x].setAuthor(author);

            //Page Input
            System.out.print("Enter the number of pages for this book: ");
            pages = input.nextInt();
            pagesArray[x].setPages(pages);

            input.nextLine();
        }

        //Book Organize input
        System.out.println("How would you like to organize your values?");
        System.out.println("Sort by title > Enter 1: ");
        System.out.println("Sort by author's last name > Enter 2: ");
        System.out.print("Sort by page count > Enter 3: ");
        sortBy = input.nextInt();



        // Sort by title
        if(sortBy == 1)
        {
            for(x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            {

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Book ");
                System.out.println("Title: " + titleArray[x].getBook());
                System.out.println("Author: " + authorArray[x].getAuthor());
                System.out.println("Page Count: " + pagesArray[x].getPages());
            }
        }
        // Sort by author
        else
        if(sortBy == 2)
        {
            for(x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Book ");
                System.out.println("Author: " + authorArray[x].getAuthor());
                System.out.println("Title: " + titleArray[x].getBook());
                System.out.println("Page Count: " + pagesArray[x].getPages());
            }
        }
        // Sort by page count
        else
        if(sortBy == 3)
        {
            for(x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Book ");
                System.out.println("Page Count: " + pagesArray[x].getPages());
                System.out.println("Title: " + titleArray[x].getBook());
                System.out.println("Author: " + authorArray[x].getAuthor());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "Arrays.sort() will not compile when used" mean?  The Java API doesn't generally contain methods that "will not compile when used".  How did you try to use it?

Comment: Don't ask the same question again and again. Edit your original question to make it clear, and answer the questions you get in comments.

Comment: for example, System.out.println("Author: " + Arrays.sort(authorArray[x].getAuthor()));   will not compile, since it is void.

Comment: @ewbrowning Did you read the comments on your previous question? `Arrays.sort` is a `void` method.

Comment: yes, yes I did. To no avail

Comment: @ewbrowning It seems that you don't know how `Arrays.sort` works. Why are you doing `Arrays.sort(authorArray[x].getAuthor())`? What's your goal when doing this?

Comment: I'm asking again because I searched and attempted various ways with 0 progress. How do you suggest I figure this out?

Comment: I'm not doing it anymore because it doesn't work.

Comment: By answering the questions you get in comments. You were being told that sorting a string didn't make any sense, and were being asked what you were trying to achieve. And you didn't gave any answer.

Comment: I understand how to sort with an array that doesn't have a class that sets and holds each inputted method

Comment: I did, I posted a link from my initial question that expressed what I was trying to achieve

Comment: You have to **explain** us what you want to do. The code doesn't tell us what you want to do, since it doesn't even compile.

Comment: I cannot use comparators, that's why I am asking how to figure this out without using them.

Comment: Just think about some of the things stated in all of your threads. Sorting _one_ String makes no sense, Arrays.sort returns void (it sorts the instance passed to it). This + some experimenting should get you on the right track

Comment: The above code compiles. I will explain what I would like again... I'm copying and pasting my statement at the top of this page... "How can I sort the arrays in my IF statements either alphabetically or numerically (pg nums)? Mind you, Arrays.sort() will not compile when used. I'm trying to sort the RETURNED values, not the initial inputs."

Comment: So you're obsessed with my syntax, I get it. I'm trying to sort the elements within the Array.

Comment: @ewbrowning If you're not able to use comparators, you can always implement your own sorting algorithm.

Comment: A String doesn't have elements. It has characters. What does sorting "hello" mean to you? It's also unclear what you mean by "initial input" and "returned value".

Comment: Like @ZouZou said, if you want to sort objects without a comparator you'd need to implement your own sorting algorithm.

Comment: using a bubble sort? I can do that, however I was wondering if there were an easier way, something similar to Arrays.sort()?

Comment: I meant to say Array**

Comment: @ewbrowning You're free to implement any implementations of existing sorting algorithms. Mind you that the algorithm used by `Arrays.sort` is more complex to implement than the bubble sort (but more efficient).

Comment: Note that your LibraryBook elements probably should contain 1 author, 1 title and 1 pages. As it is, the name is confusing. The easy way would be a correct LibraryBook definition with custom comparators.

Answer (score 0):

If `Arrays.sort` won't compile, you're Doing It Wrong. In any case, you need to define custom `Comparator<LibraryBook>` objects that each compare the relevant field, and then sort using those. If you're going to keep multiple data structures anyway, might as well make them `SortedSet`s instead of plain arrays.